# how to do circular shift in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, shift

I have a numpy array, for example

```
a = np.arange(10)
```

how can I move the first `n` elements to the end of the array?

I found this [`roll`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) function but it seems like it only does the opposite, which shifts the last `n` elements to the beginning.

Comment: Isn't `roll` exactly what you want?  Instead of moving the first `n` elements to the end, move the last `len(a)-n` elements to the beginning?

Comment: Post some data of what you want vs. what you are finding.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Why not just `roll` with a negative number?

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(10)
>>> np.roll(a,2)
array([8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
>>> np.roll(a,-2)
array([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1])
```

Answer (score 8):

you can use negative shift

```
a = np.arange(10)
print(np.roll(a, 3))
print(np.roll(a, -3))
```

returns

> [7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>   [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2]

Comment: Can you tell me ,why circshift (eye (m), 2) and numpy.roll(numpy.eye(m), -2)) yield different result?

Comment: 1.) what is circshift? 2) comments it's not the correct place to ask questions disconnected with the question

Comment: @FrancescoMontesano `circshift` is a [MATLAB function](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/circshift.html).

Comment: I don't know Matlab.My wild guess is: index from 0 or 1; column- vs. row-first ordering; ...

Comment: @Gunjannaik numpy.roll uses a peculiar default behaviour for 'axis': "By default, the array is flattened before shifting, after which the original shape is restored.". You'll probably need axis=(0,1) to have the behaviour of the two functions match.